# What does flashing prompt do during finisher in Astral Chain?

Tags: astral-chain

In Astral Chain, after lowering chimera's health to certain in point, player can use finisher attack - Legion will pull out chimera's core and consume it. It heals player (and probably Legion), and gives more Gene Code than usual enemy kill.

Yet, I can't get one thing about this mechanic. When fighting certain enemies, when performing finisher, character will wait until player presses ZL to actually perform finisher. And if you wait enough, there is flashing prompt, similar to Sync Attack prompt. I'm trying to press ZL during this prompt, but nothing seemingly changes.

So what does this flashing prompt do?